# Is there a general option in gcc to change the compile output suffix for any file?

Tags: gcc, ide

I have an IDE that uses gcc and it outputs compiled objects as .o files. However, there is also a CMake version for the same project that outputs compiled objects as .obj files.  As a result I would need two linker files to manage the discrepancy between them.  I would like to know if there is a gcc option that tells the compiler to output .obj instead of .o so that I can just maintain a single linker file.
I'm not looking for a simple `-o` option where I need to provide the filename prefix but rather a general option that I can include in the IDE set of options to apply to all C files. Thanks

Comment: There is no gcc option to separately manage file suffixes. If you need to provide a file name to gcc, you just provide the file name, including the suffix.

Comment: Technically, what you want might be doable by means of a specs file https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html But it may be quite tricky to get right.  Better tell your magical IDE what to do, or switch from automatic build to owm Makefile, CMake, or whatever.